# How to donwload/save video in Chrome on iOS?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I have a React app with a video player on a page. The player is made with a `<video>` html tag. There's a `Donwload video` button under the player and onClick handler on it. On click this function fires:

```
const downloadFile = (url: string) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.click();
};
```

It works nice on PC, the file downloads without any problems. But when I try to download a file from iPhone then a video opens in fullscreen without ability to download/save it to iPhone. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey could you please try this if this helps...

```
const downloadFile = (url: string, filename: string) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.setAttribute('download', filename);
  a.click();
};
```

Please let me know if this works..!